# Why did the running applications disappear in the Fedora taskbar?

Tags: fedora, taskbar

I can't see the running applications in the task bar. I can only use <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> to switch.

How can I bring it back?

Answer (score 1):

You probably just (accidently) removed the Window List.

Right click on your panel (task bar), choose Add to Panel, find the Window List and add it.